# How to get body of Cosmos DB Stored Procedure request?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, server-side-scripting

When querying my Cosmos DB Stored Procedure from Postman I get the following error and I don't understand why:

```
{
   "code": "BadRequest",
   "message": "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getBody'\\r\\nStack trace: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getBody'\\n   at storedProcedure (Test.js:7:9)\\n   at __docDbMain (Test.js:13:5)\\n   at Global code (Test.js:1:2)\"]}\r\nActivityId: f01827c0-4992-4560-bec1-e015b5678cf8, Request URI: /apps/ce1979d6-d776-4e39-bc44-85912cdd1c9f/services/95b9183f-4865-4ddb-933b-1869cb325207/partitions/b7168d10-e69f-4dae-87d8-91a07e5d6cfd/replicas/131638498361729976p/, RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.20.0.0"
}
```

The SP I've created is really simple:

```js
function storedProcedure(){

        var context = getContext();
        var response = context.getResponse();

        var item = context.getRequest().getBody();

        response.setBody(item);
}
```

It seems like the getRequest method is unable to find the request as other request methods (found here http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-js-server/) fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

The body is available as the argument to the stored procedure. For example, if you change the definition to the following, you can get the case:

```
function storedProcedure(body){
    var context = getContext();
    var response = context.getResponse();
    response.setBody(body);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean **response.setBody(body);**? If I just want to return the body. In that case I get a 200 http response with the following body: Unexpected 'u'.

The body in my request is {"test": "1234"}.